# After python program imported and run variables persist in IDLE but not at cmd (win) or terminal (osx)

Tags: python, windows, macos, cmd

I have set up my programming environment on win pc and mac osx using notepad++ and text-wrangler respectively. On both computers I have set up a shortcut/alias to the python34->lib-> site-packages so I can quickly import my programs from the interpreter prompt. On the win pc I have included this line in the environment variables path:

C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages

This allows me to access python 3.4 from cmd 
On OSX terminal I simply launch the interpreter by typing python3

All this works great to run small code examples that I am working through in text books but why is it that variables in the imported modules seem to be only temporary? While in IDLE if I open the same file and run the 
variables are still recognized.

example

```
test.py 

word = 'pizza' 

print(

'''
Slicing "Cheat Sheet"

0    1    2    3   4    5

 +---+---+----+----+----+
 |  p  |  i  |  z |  z |  a |
 +---+---+----+---+-----+
-5   -4   -3   -2   -1 

''' 
)

print ('Enter the beginning and ending index for your slice of "pizza".')
print ('Press the enter key at the "Begin" to exit.')

start = ''

while start == '': 
    start = (input('\nStart: '))


    if start: 
        start = int(start)

        finish = int(input('Finish: '))

        print('word [', start, ':', finish, '] is', end=' ')
        print(word[start:finish])

input ('\n\nPress the enter key to exit.')
```

importing this at cmd or terminal runs the code. but after typing variable word at prompt gives

nameerror name 'word'is not defined

whereas in IDLE after the module has run typing in the variable word will give the assigned expression 'pizza'. Why is this?

Comment: You should use `python -i test.py` to run the script and then interact with the result in Python's shell.

Comment: Also, remove the `site-packages` directory from `PATH`. There shouldn't be scripts in that directory, only modules that get found via Python's `sys.path`.

Comment: python -i test.py doesn't work. Returns 'can't open file test.py: [Errno 2] no such file or directory.

Comment: Have also removed the site packages directory from PATH and have installed PIP and setuptools so hopefully this will allow me to install and run my scripts.

Comment: Added PYTHONPATH variable to windows environment variables with my directory as a value. Don't think I really need PIP and setuptools at this stage as I'm not writing code to be used by anybody else but I'm sure as I figure this stuff out that I may find them useful. Thanks piezol and @eryksun

Comment: This is a script that should be run with the special name `__main__` (i.e. I'm sure you've seen `if __name__ == "__main__"` tests in examples). It's not a library to be installed in site-packages or in a custom `PYTHONPATH` directory. Provide a relative or absolute path to the script, or put it in a `PATH` directory and run it directly as just `test.py`.

Comment: cmd.exe is not a integrated development environment (IDE) for anything except batch (.bat) files. You don't "import" a script from cmd.exe; you run it as a child process. The process doesn't run "in" cmd.exe. The python.exe process inherits its console window from cmd.exe, and cmd.exe waits in the background for python.exe to exit. That console window is created and hosted by conhost.exe. That's basically the Windows equivalent of a Unix pty / terminal emulator combination, but less flexible since a process can attach to one and only one console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you import it?

```
from test.py import *
```

should import all the variables into namespace.

Simple "import" does not let you use names used in imported file

[HERE](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-whats-the-difference-between-import-foo-and-from-foo-import.htm) is more about that.
But generally speaking, global variables in separate file or creating a class would be cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're importing just like "import test". Then of course, it's not `word`, but `test.word`. You can do `from test import word`, or even `from test import *`, but I guess I don't have to tell you it's not a good practice usually (but then again, much of what you're doing is not good practice:).

Why it works in IDLE? Probably because you've *also* run your file as a script (F5) at some time.

Comment: I'm a beginner to python and programming so I don't know what good practice would be. If it works and it's not explicitly mentioned that it shouldn't be done at python.org what would make it bad practice?

Comment: So if the file is run as a script does that mean that it has been made executable? Tried the from test import word and that worked. Thanks.

Comment: Guido is explicitly against running modules as scripts (or vice-versa, importing your scripts). Python is just not optimized for that usage. -m is different from -i. There are many problems (for example, `import x` works only once per session; namespacing issues you've encoundered are another), and many more when you start writing packages. Not to mention messing with PYTHONPATH all the time. Just invoke python as `python -i test.py` (or use F5 in IDLE). And making a script executable has nothing to do with it, that is a shell thing (that you probably don't need). Continued...

Comment: Link for the above: http://blindvic.blogspot.com/2012/04/guido-views-running-scripts-within.html And now the more important thing. Your mode of using Python is wrong. This kind of thing (experimenting with various values of parameters) is exactly what REPL (read-eval-print loop, like what you have in IDLE or python invoked interactively) is for. In fact you've written a primitive REPL, and a very inflexible one. Just write a function if you want (but hey, writing `word[` all the time is not _so_ bad:), and invoke it as you like from the real REPL. `input` is not for developers, but for users.

Comment: I don't understand most of what you have written here but I do appreciate you taking the time to explain and linking to further material. A lot to learn! Thanks Veky. :-)

Comment: Hm, SO probably isn't the right medium for this... anyway, just write your scripts in IDLE and execute them with F5; or write them in ordinary text files and execute them with `python -i`. Use `import` for libraries, it's what it's designed for.